# How to format a Double value properly with decimal separator?

Tags: android, string-formatting, number-formatting, decimalformat

I have an application that uses thousands separator (,) and decimal separator (.), I used this app on 2 tablets with the same languages (Español) on their configuration and when I do some process with numbers like 15,000.00 on the first one the answer was correct but in the second tablet the number changes to 15,00. I changed the language of the second to English, and it works, but how can i set this number format on code?

Sorry about the errors this is not my native language.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could format using

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(new Locale("es", "MX")); //for example
```

But beware because depending on the locale, even if is the same language but different country the decimal char and grouping char my change, for example

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(new Locale("es", "CO")); //displays 15.000,00
```

Comment: I tryed this and the format was good but puts $ at the begin of the string and I'm using numbers like percents, is there a way to delete this char?

Comment: Try with `NumberFormat.getPercentInstance(locale);`

Comment: solved it deleting the simbol of the string using substring, thanks for the help

Answer (score 4):

You could format a double value in code like this:

```
/**
 * format a number properly
 * @param number
 * @return
 */
public String formatDecimal(double number) {

    DecimalFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("###.###.###.##0,00");
    // or this way: nf = new DecimalFormat("###,###,###,##0.00");

    String formatted = nf.format(number);

    return formatted;
}
```

And then set it to a TextView:

```
mytextview.setText("MyDouble: " + formatDecimal(somedouble));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get an instance for a specific locale as specified by the [android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/NumberFormat.html):

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.FRENCH);
```

However, you should not change the locale when displaying stuff to the user imho.